# How to disprove the statement...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Statement:
There are an infinite number of primes of the form 4N+1 and a finite number of primes of the form 4N-1.

How would you disprove this ?

Comment: __Hint:__ There is an infinite number of primes of the form $4N -1$.

Comment: I tried using that approach but how can you be sure that the new prime is of he form 4N-1 and not 4N+1, I am referring to Euclid's proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There is an infinite number of primes of the form $4N -1$.

Proof: By contradiction. Suppose not. Let the primes of the form $4N-1$ be $p_1, p_2, \ldots p_k$.

Consider the number $$ A = 4 p_1 p_2 \ldots p_k - 1.$$

**Hint:** Show that there must be a prime of the form $4N-1$ that divides $A$.

Comment: How do you know whether or not the new prime is of the form 4N+1?

Comment: Note that $(4a+1)(4b+1)=4(4ab+a+b)+1$

Comment: OH ok so the number must have factors of the form (4a+1)(4b-1). OK thanks.

Comment: @user129967 At least one of them anyway.  An odd number of them.  Note that a similar proof will not work for $4N+1$.

Comment: Yes I understand why. Thanks.